# In Celery tasking, is the database scheduler sufficient, or do I need to specify the run_every property as well?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a periodic task that is supposed to run once a day, but currently it runs twice a day, and I'm not sure why.  The second run occurs milliseconds after the intended one.

My periodic task has the **run_every** property specified:

> run_every = crontab(hour=1, minute=1)

but in my settings file, the database scheduler is specified:

> CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'

furthermore in the database, there are tables with the task names and their crontab schedule.
For example we have a table called djcelery_crontabschedule and it also specifies that the same task should run at 1:01 am.

Could this be causing my task to run twice every day?

Answer (score 0):

I never use `run_every`... Here is an example from the beatconfig.py file that I use:

```
beat_schedule = {
    'company-data-report': {
        'task': 'report.company_data_report',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=7),
        'args': [],
        'options': {'expires': 120*60}
    },
    etc
```

This particular task runs every day at specified time. We use the default Celery scheduler, not some third-party implementation.